# Creating a Spring Bean for Neo4j Graph Database

Tags: spring, neo4j

I noticed that in the latest stable version(1.9) of Neo4j, the recommended way of creating a `GraphDatabaseService` is through the `GraphDatabaseFactory` and the `HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory`.

Previous in 1.8.2, we were able to create a Spring Bean using the `EmbeddedGraphDatabase` and `HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase`:

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg name="storeDir" value="<storeDir>" />
    <constructor-arg name="params" ref="<configuration>" />
</bean>
```

But with this new version, we cannot call the fluent pattern using Spring through XML. I noticed that the older versions have been deprecated, so I'd like to upgrade to the Factories, but I cannot seem to resolve these in Spring.

Also, if I use the builder/factory, I cannot specify the `destroy-method` of shutdown so that the Graph Database will shutdown safely when spring is destroyed.

Is there a way to use the Builder/Factory pattern that Neo4j is utilizing in Spring XML?

Comment: Good point, we should provide a factory bean for those or XML config attributes. So for now please go with the deprecated version and please raise an issue at http://spring.neo4j.org/issues

Comment: That's for Spring Data, mind if I file it in the Neo4j Github?